# Should all thrown exceptions be handled somewhere?

Tags: c#, exception

Is it bad practice to throw an exception and not handle it? for example, if I have a number that returns true on Double.IsNaN() when it shouldn't ever return true, is it ok for me to crash the program by throwing an exception? what exactly is the point of "handling" the exception if there is no graceful way to continue operation when the event occurs?

Comment: If there is no graceful way to handle it.. then your app should die a gigantic horribly violent death. That is much better than possibly continuing with corrupt state.

Comment: `is it ok for me to crash the program by throwing an exception?` -- Is it OK for your program to crash under the stated conditions?

Comment: @Simon Whitehead, good advise you should make your comment an official answer.

Comment: Unhandled exceptions are not exactly crashes.  They are more like an orderly exit under abnormal conditions.  An exception, whether handled or unhandled, is what happens when the code says "I can't do anything about this." A crash is what happens when you get a blue screen of death, or your process is terminated by the OS because it is writing to memory it's not supposed to, or something similarly catastrophic.  An unhandled exception is not exactly catastrophic; no kittens will be harmed.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Harm can come to kittens if important program execution is not correctly recovered :>

Comment: @user2246674: Ergo, my original question to the OP: *Is it OK for your program to crash under the stated conditions?*

Comment: thanks everyone. I'm guessing then that it's ok to have an unhandled exception just to warn you if an event that shouldn't happen happens. Though from the user's point of view they probably prefer some handled exception with an error dialog box or something. I just think that this exception should never happen and feel like catching the exception and displaying some gui element with the warning message is too much work for something that really should not happen unless I make changes to the code elsewhere that someday break this section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no harm in adding an exception where a basic sanity check is violated. The only time such an exception should ever occur should be during testing, if you've mistakenly assumed something is axiomatic that actually isn't. You don't necessarily need to handle such an exception.

If what you're talking about is corrupt state that *may* occur during normal program operation, but that you have no way of dealing with in the current layer of the application, it seems you need another layer which will recover from the error, communicate to the user (or whatever interfaces with your code) and take appropriate action. "Appropriate action" could be anything from logging errors and terminating to asking the user for further instructions. Leaving this kind of exception unhandled is not a good idea.

Comment: these posts were really informative for me, and even though the post is opinion based, I find that as a new programmer, hearing opinions helps me think about the issue better

Answer (score 1):

I don't like not handling exceptions even if all you do is inform the user that things have gone south then call exit.  That is pretty much what not handling the exception will do anyway except you can try to give a better error diagnostic than the default unhandled exception.  It would also give you the chance to log the exception so that the user can send in the error message by attaching the log file.  Other than that crashing is an acceptable solution to the "state is so corrupted I don't know which end is up any more" problem.